# Install USB 3.0 to HDMI display Graphic Converter adapter for Xubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, xubuntu

I have this [adapter](https://www.lazada.co.th/products/i2720737724-s9850344496.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1&spm=spm%3Da2o4m.order_details.item_title.1) on USB 3.1 Gen 1 port of my notebook [HP 14ck0023TU](https://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c06035282).
[It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efz9V.png) works fine [in Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWVcq.png).
And these are [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1nH2.png) stored in this adapter.

```
root@office001:/home/office001# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0408:5310 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0065 SiGma Micro Optical Wheel Mouse [Rapoo N1130]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 534d:6021 MacroSilicon VGA Display Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@office001:/home/office001#
```

Is it possible to find equivalent driver and how to install in Xubuntu 21.10 ?

Comment: AFAIK, unlike DisplayLink adapters, yours have zero support for Linux.

Comment: Hi! wonder if you find how to get it working. Thanks!!

Comment: Dear @titockmente, I sold that notebook and bought a new mini pc  and did the dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 11.